# Select Row from Other Table if Doesn't Exist in Current Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

Table1

```
id   name       qty
1    Tedd       6
2    Jim        7
3    Sally      8
4    Victoria   1
```

Table2

```
id   name       qty
1    Tedd       2
2    Jim        2
3    Sally      2
4    Victoria   1
5    Alex       9
```

I need to select all the rows from Table1. However, if a row exists in Table2 that doesn't exist in Table1, I need to include that in the result set. So, in the end, my query should return this:

```
id   name       qty
1    Tedd       6
2    Jim        7
3    Sally      8
4    Victoria   1
5    Alex       9
```

Is there a way I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
select 
  coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) id,
  coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) name,
  coalesce(t1.qty, t2.id) qty
from table1 t1
full outer join table2 t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8cfd7/2)